# open jquery mobile dialog in backbone view

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, view, dialog

Is it possible to open an JQuery-mobile dialog from backbone view programmatically, I tried and searched a lot without any answers.
 I tried to call $(selector).dialog(options) but nothing happens.

I use backbone together with JQuery-mobile.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code (perhaps at http://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Well, I tried with dialog() function which doesnt work, and I switched to change page, but the problem is when dialog is closing, I return to a blank page. system is quite large and complicated, difficult to fix in jsfiddle.net